# How to ignore parent's width limit in CSS

Tags: html, css, markdown, jekyll

**An example of my code:**

Check this link https://jsfiddle.net/b5woxesg/

**Explaining:**

My website's content was placed like this to keep itself in the center of the page. With `width:` in % and `max-width:` in px to not strech.
This content is called from a Markdown file, since I am using jekyll.

What I want to do is: whenever I call the `{% highlight %}`in the MD file, the code block the is generated should be with `width: 100%` but ignoring the parent's width limit. I mean 100% of the whole page. Also, the text inside should keep in alignment with the page content. Something like that:

[image]

But the highlight div is inside the content with blue border.

I believe that there's no way to do this without changing the current structure, I have no problem with that, but since i'm using a MD file, some changes can be restricted.

**@EDIT: Solution:**

Thank you all for the help.

I used the `@MD Ashik` tip and improved it with a easy jQuery code that save the .highlight `height` (since I'm using `height: auto` the height could be any number).
Then I created a `div class="space"` next to the .highlight, that only is used to fill the space in the content. So I set the .space div with the exactly `height` of .highlight

Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/b5woxesg/7/

Comment: @CBroe I really want to avoid that. I believe that theres a easy way to do this but I just cant see it right now. :(

Comment: I am surprised, It's really great idea. Thanks #Maico Williams

Also Thanks @Pang for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Live Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/w5zz2g8e/1/)

Yes it's possible only change by CSS.
By few change:

1. just make     `position: absolute;`to `relative` on class `.page`.
2. and add CSS in .highlight class

   ```
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   ```

solve it if you need anything more just make a comment.

Comment: Aw, I tried so many ways but forgot about it. Works. The div is full on left and with 100%. Of course the content below the highlight div is now under it. But the main issue is solved. Thanks.

Comment: Your most welcome so I hop  you make my answer right with green sign.

Comment: Since the highlight div is absolute, the content is not considering its height, moving the div above the content. Any thoughts on that? https://jsfiddle.net/b5woxesg/5/

Comment: Any comment for negative vot ?

Answer (score 38):

If you don't want to use positioning to achieve this, you can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-with-fixed-width">
    <div class="fluid"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fluid {
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
}
```

Comment: There is still an horizontal offset due to the scrollbar thickness I think. So this can cut off content.

Comment: It does work, but at this point I think in my case it's time to realize I've structured the document badly and need to change that. (Note to self: Don't set `max-width` on the `html` tag.)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}

.highlight:before,
.highlight:after {
  background: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  width: 40px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
}
.highlight:before {
  left: -12.5%;
}

.highlight:after {
  right: -12.6%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b5woxesg/3/

Comment: But Your code is not responsive, Please solve it. http://codepen.io/ashikjs/full/GjbKON/

Comment: @developernator Also a great answer. It's not even setting the highlight div as absolute. Awesome. I believe that I still will have issues considering that I use `height: auto` for the highlight div. am I right?

Comment: @MD Just make the width larger on the .highlight to cover your "theoretical situations" .

Comment: @Maico correct on the height.  If there's a different situation in which it needs it with other then the link to fiddle you provided I am glad to help

Comment: sure, so it's not better for device change ?

Comment: @MD Tying to break the solution in other examples is not what the questioned ask. I solved the exact fiddle provided.

Comment: @MD solved: https://jsfiddle.net/b5woxesg/4/

Comment: @developernatro sure your right but he don't work only in fiddle so we need correct solution for all device . like responsive code .

Comment: And where's your working CSS example for your "solution" provided?

Comment: You already see my solution men. it's under your answer .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126948/discussion-between-md-ashik-and-developernator).

Comment: men? are there two of me?

Comment: @developernatro Sure

Comment: @developernator it's currently stretching my page to 3000px width. Im trying to find a workaround but isn't working

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/b5woxesg/6/

You can't put position absolute because element will be overflowed. Hilarious advice ever in my life. Mūṛha uttara. I am new in programming and this can also answer your problem. Learn more about javascript. I just started learning javascript 2days ago. So, it may not be perfect.

```js
let page = document.getElementById('page'),
 content = document.getElementById('content'),
 highlight = document.getElementById('highlight'),
  pageStyle = window.getComputedStyle(page, null);
  
highlight.style.width = pageStyle.getPropertyValue('width');
highlight.style.marginLeft = `-${content.offsetLeft + 1}px`

window.onresize = () => {
 highlight.style.width = pageStyle.getPropertyValue('width');
 highlight.style.marginLeft = `-${content.offsetLeft + 1}px`
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0 10px;
}
.content {
  width: 80%;
  max-width 200px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  color: black;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page" id="page">
  <div class="content" id="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis nec mattis est. Donec eget hendrerit lacus. Ut aliquet hendrerit lacinia. Mauris auctor rhoncus turpis ac tempus.
    <div class="highlight" id="highlight">
      <b>highlight</b>
    </div>
    Donec non imperdiet urna, nec cursus magna. Suspendisse ligula erat, consequat quis est ac, sollicitudin placerat diam.
  </div>
</div>
```

oson savol tentak.

Comment: Hey Arteezy, nice nick btw. I've solved the issue with MD Ashik tip + some jQuery code. check it out. https://jsfiddle.net/b5woxesg/7/  Thanks for your comment. @Edit: great coding. Idk if you know well about jQuery but it can make your coding more easy, like I did. Nice job anyways

Comment: Yeah @MaicoWilliams Great. I know jQuery. I learn it first. But since I focus on UX. I prefer performance. There's a big difference between the performance of native and jquery.

Comment: @user7083298 really your a good programer. your code is working 100% . Clean code. Thanks for your Right Answer

Answer (score 1):

Even if this is already solved, for future reference, here's a solution to your fiddle without using any Javascript.

[image]

It takes into account that it's inside a div with 80% width for calculating the correct width (width + paddings) and that its grand-parent (is that even a technical term? :)) is a div with 50% width for calculating the negative margins. It should be fairly easy to adapt to other situations.

Simply add to `.highlight`:

```
width: 101.1%;
padding-left: 12%;
padding-right: 12%;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
right: 50%;
margin-left: -25vw;
margin-right: -25vw;
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dzrne1uo/1/

You might want to check out [this article](https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/) for more information.